# Play WS - post multipart/form-data from scala - Bad Request

Tags: scala, playframework, multipartform-data

I am trying to post pdf file to external service with multipart/form-data request. I've done this with sample Java Script client so the external service works properly. Hovewer in scala with the following code I got: Bad request:

```
import akka.stream.scaladsl.FileIO
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Source
import play.api.libs.ws.WSClient
import play.api.mvc.MultipartFormData._

val pathToFile = "./sampleCV.pdf"
val fileName = "sampleCV.pdf"
val futureResponse = ws.url(url).withRequestTimeout(Duration.create(55, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
      .addHttpHeaders("authorization" -> s"bearer $access_token")
      .addHttpHeaders("accept" -> "*/*")
      .addHttpHeaders("content-type" -> "multipart/form-data")
      .post(Source(
        FilePart("File", fileName, Option("application/pdf"), FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get(pathToFile)))  :: List()
      ))
```

Play version: 2.6.19

Following curl command upload the file properly:

`curl -X POST "https://rest_url" -H "accept: */*" -H "Authorization: bearer <TOKEN>" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "File=@sampleCV.pdf;type=application/pdf"`

Did I miss some important parameter in `post(...)` ? What are appropriate post parameters in ScalaWS which corresponds to this CURL request?

Comment: First check your request, for example using cURL

Comment: I edited question and added example curl POST which works with this service. Thanks!

Comment: Header `accept` differ, also file field `File` != `cv` and check the token (which as a Scala value should rather be named `accessToken`)

Comment: Done - result the same- Bad Request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When multipart/form-data is used, a boundary parameter is required. The Content-Type header is going to look something like this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=nZaYg9TFHoDaLWhs8w
```

You set the Content-Type header using `addHttpHeaders`, but since it lacks the boundary parameter, it doesn't work.
The solution is to not set that header manually, in fact you should never need to set that header. Play-WS will add an appropriate Content-Type header based on the type of object that you pass to the `post` method. When you pass a `Source[Part[Source[ByteString, Any]]]`, it will set the multipart/form-data Content-Type and also add an appropriate boundary parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, adding Content-Length header solved in mycase. Added header as below to WSRequest,

```
wsRequest.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(fileToUpload.length()));
```

Here fileToUpload is java.io.File object which you are trying to upload.