# How to upload upload image/file to akamai server using play framework

Tags: java, file-upload, playframework, akamai, ws-client

This is the code in scala how can we do a similar thing in java using the play framework
reference: -> [Play WS - post multipart/form-data from scala - Bad Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63577224/play-ws-post-multipart-form-data-from-scala-bad-request)

```
import akka.stream.scaladsl.FileIO
    import akka.stream.scaladsl.Source
    import play.api.libs.ws.WSClient
    import play.api.mvc.MultipartFormData._
    
    val pathToFile = "./sampleCV.pdf"
    val fileName = "sampleCV.pdf"
    val futureResponse = ws.url(url).withRequestTimeout(Duration.create(55, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
          .addHttpHeaders("authorization" -> s"bearer $access_token")
          .addHttpHeaders("accept" -> "*/*")
          .addHttpHeaders("content-type" -> "multipart/form-data")
          .post(Source(
            FilePart("File", fileName, Option("application/pdf"), FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get(pathToFile)))  :: List()
          ))
```

I had tried but got 412 as the response code as I was using an HTTP multipart file.

Comment: how to do this scala code into java:
ws.url(url).post(Source(FilePart("hello", "hello.txt", Option("text/plain"), FileIO.fromFile(tmpFile)) :: DataPart("key", "value") :: List()))

reference -> https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWS

Comment: i am getting :- after tring this approach :-> https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaWS
Hi, I'm trying to retrieve the JSON response from my API but I'm having a problem if the status code is 412. It just keeps on loading and no response is being returned. Any reason for this?

Comment: it worked for me -> playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaWS

I was passing the wrong headers authenticated and URL combination without HTTPS
which worked after providing hostname with HTTPS